# Unexpected end of input jquery using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am having the following jQuery script.

http://www.codeshare.io/aQxBp

And getting the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

My js file is correct on syntax side, do not missing any closing or opening bracket. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Try removing the "http://www.codeshare.io/new" from `}http://www.codeshare.io/new`

Comment: ah wel, it seems i do not get your point. you entered `http://www.codeshare.io/new`

should i remove what again, please?

Comment: It appears your code is working now. You had that url uncommented in your code. That would cause your error.

Comment: btw, there is no problem with the if includes the `#emailtoinvite` the problem is still occurs when that code snippet is removed.

Comment: actually that url was not added by me. idk how is that got it there. :) 

check it now: http://www.codeshare.io/aQxBp

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. The strange thing is that the script itself working because the php method is called properly, everything is working beside the success part of my JS.

Comment: Ah, that's easy then. You are telling your ajax call to expect JSON to be returned. You are not getting proper JSON. Please provide your results from the success message. If you are having an issue testing, you can try Developer Tools in Google Chrome and then go to the "Network" tab to see what is actually being returned from the ajax call to "sendinvitation.php".

Comment: yeah view watching it for a while here is what i am getting: 

`emailtoinvite:zilahi@gmail.com
idToInvite:136`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The here is that you are telling your ajax call to expect to receive JSON. When JSON is not received, an error will be thrown when JSON.parse tries to parse a non-JSON string. JSON is fairly simple in nature but you have to be intentional. To make an ajax call similar to this (note `response.emailtoinvite`):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    url: "sendinvitation.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
    dataType: "json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    data: myData, //Form variables
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.emailtoinvite);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //$(".btn.btn-primary").show(); //show submit button
        alert(thrownError);
    }

});
```

....sendinvitation.php will have to send back a proper JSON string. The following works:

```
{emailtoinvite: "zilahi@gmail.com", idToInvite: 136}
```

Important things to note here, all strings must be wrapped in double quotation marks `""`. Also, the entire string must be wrapped in `{}`. numbers can be left without quotes around them.

Also important to note that the above is **not** proper syntax, but does sometimes work. Proper syntax also requires you to wrap you "keys" in quotes `""` as well:

```
{"emailtoinvite": "zilahi@gmail.com", "idToInvite": 136}
```

Comment: thanks i guess i got it but still do not have any idea what to change in my code to make that work, becasue i am simply getting the id as the following: 

`idToInvite: this.getAttribute("data-eventId")`

Comment: Oh man. Ok so scratch that. That's fine. I need to know what is being returned from the ajax call. What is "sendinvitation.php" `echo`ing? That's all that matters.

Comment: actually sendinvitation.php is getting some data from sql, then calls a simple method. i can only show you the Form Data from Network i already posted above:

`emailtoinvite:zilahi@gmail.com
idToInvite:136`

i think i do get the problem causing the error, the thing with proper JSON thingy.

What else do you need? I can show you the whole php if needed....

Comment: Yeah, send me the part where PHP is `echo`ing.

Comment: You are showing me what you are sending. On the Network tab, click on the XHR (ajax) call and then click on "Response". I already understand what you are sending (from the browser), I need to see the response (from the server).

Comment: this is what you are referring to? 

http://people.inf.elte.hu/zirtaai/photobucket/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-01%20at%2023.24.15.png

Comment: Yep, that's it exactly. You are not sending anything back. The problem is with PHP, not javascript. In your PHP script type this `echo '{"hello": "world"}'` (just for testing purposes). You should find your javascript errors disappear. You still have work to do in PHP though.

Comment: Actually this has solved the problem. This is really interesting! Anyhow, thank you for putting time into my issue! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Feel free to select this answer so that people will know that your problem was solved. :)

Comment: I was trying to return the json object and not echo it lol. If I'd only seen your answer KJ Price, I would have saved a few hours of hair pulling.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url:"test.php",//<?php echo $_GET['url'] ?>,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if ($('#toggle').prop('checked')) {
                    $('.led-<?php echo $_GET[\'color\'] ?>').show();
                    $('.led-off').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.led-<?php echo $_GET[\'color\'] ?>').hide();
                    $('.led-off').show();
                }
            },
        });
```

Comment: explaining what was the problem with the user's code would be good for your answer. Also, try to add code into code format, and, make indentation or code formating always as possible.